# Error in aws-amplify style.css while running the npm test

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

Had issue while running the npm test

```
C:\projects\Test\node_modules\@aws-amplify\ui\dist\style.css:13:root {^
```

error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/aws-amplify-react/src/Amplify-UI/Amplify-UI-Components-React.jsx:5:1)
```

here are my import statements

`import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import { AuthPiece } from 'aws-amplify-react';
import { Auth, Logger, JS } from 'aws-amplify';`

If I comment out the `style.css` it works without any errors.
But how can I remove this issue so that it doesnt cause issue to others when I commit code.

Had checked all the existing answers provided in different forums.But that doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well, and [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3094) helped me resolve it. In my case, I needed to install `identity-obj-proxy` package and map it to the jest config:

`npm install --save-dev identity-obj-proxy`

`package.json`

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
```

I hope this helps!